# Is there a way to adjust or set an android device's camera exposure from an AR unity app built with Vuforia?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm working on an AR app in Unity, using unity 2021.3.11f1 and Vuforia 10.10.2. The app is intended to be used in a relatively dimly lit indoor environment. The problem I'm encountering is the in app feed coming from the device camera is very dark. When I view the same room with the same lighting through the device's camera app it looks fine, the exposure is automatically adjusting to the environment. What I'm wondering is if anyone knows if there's a way to set the exposure of the camera higher through Unity or Vuforia's unity plugin.

I've been looking through the documentation for Unity and Vuforia to see if there's an existing method of drilling down to a device camera settings. Haven't found anything yet but I'll update if I do. I noted a similar question from 2017 with 0 definitive answers. Both Unity and Vuforia have developed since then so I'm hoping there might be more recent solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuforia Engine has a native API to control the exposure region (see here https://library.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/native/group__CameraControllerGroup.html#ga7e49ec7a1b2ff85bbab559d9e753ff18). However this is not available in the Unity extension yet.

Beside this, Vuforia Engine on Android uses ARCore API for camera control which at the time of writing does not have a way to control exposure (see this feature request https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/153).

It is possible for Vuforia to use the native camera directly without ARCore by setting a different Fusion Provider (https://library.vuforia.com/environments/vuforia-fusion#fusion-apis). This is likely to enable exposure controls in Engine native API. However it comes at a price: some engine features (e.g., Device Tracker) need ARCore to function properly (see https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/recommended-devices).

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to look into how to implement your recommendation regarding the different Fusion Provider. Really appreciate the help.